# How to correctly return value from method in Django?

Tags: django, function, return

I'm trying to write a method which would sum the view_count values from my "pages" in models, but for some reason the result that i get on the template is written in a weird fashion `Overall views: {'view_count__sum': 9}`

The model looks like this:

```
class Page(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
        content = models.TextField(blank=True)
        view_count = models.IntegerField (default= 0)
        edits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is a snippet of my view in which i tried to define a context method for my templates:

```
def context_count(request):
    page_count = Page.objects.count()
    tracker = Page.objects.all().aggregate(Sum(F('view_count'), output_field=IntegerField()))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tracker
    return { 'page_quantity':page_count, 'page_viewcount':tracker}
```

Just to make sure i fill you in fully, this is the line of code which my template uses to display the variable

```
<p>
    Overall views: {{page_viewcount}}
</p>
```

I realize that I have skipped over something basic, but I appreciate any input that i get on this.

Comment: Your view must return an `HttpResponse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset):

> aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked,
> returns a **dictionary of name-value pairs**.

`tracker` is a dictionary. So you need to return this:

```
return {'page_quantity': page_count, 'page_viewcount': tracker['view_count__sum']}
```